# Add lens distortion to a camera object

Tags: rendering, camera

I have a simple scene with a cube and a camera. I can save an image from the camera view, export intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters, and use them with other software. In the camera lens section, I can see few parameters, as sensor size and fit.
Now I want to add some lens distortion to the camera, like radial distortion.
I don't want to correct or distort an image in the Movie Clip Editor, but apply it to the 3D scene.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: afaik, not in current versions of blender.  you could add camera distortion in the compositor, but you'd have to modify the render engine to add it to the camera.

Comment: Is there any example of how to add some custom behavior to an existing engine (I.e eevee)? I just found [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html).